# Encode sequence of images into video for Youtube using C++

Tags: c++, youtube, h.264

I am wanting to take a sequence of images and convert them into a video for YouTube in a way that will maximise image quality for Youtube. From what I've read it seems H.264 is the best way to do this. What I want to know is what is the best way\library to do this. I've seen a few solutions but I am not looking for a complete media solution, just a simple and efficient way in inputting images (and maybe audio at the end) and outputting a video file that can then be uploaded to Youtube in such a way to doesn't cause loss of image quality due to it having to be reencoded. I'd prefer to use C++, as it is best suited to this type of thing, but C# will do as well if it will make things a lot easier.

Comment: You could use [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) if you want to do everything programmatically, or you could write the images out to disk and launch ffmpeg.

Comment: Gstream seems to be more of a complete media solution and I can't write the images to disk due to lack of resources.

Comment: Then gstreamer is probably the way to go. You can assemble a pipeline out of elements. You can create a custom source element into which you can feed images, have that run through an h264 encoder, mux it into at mkv container, and pipe the output wherever you want.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on how to do that?